# How do I troubleshoot a segmentation fault(core dumped) error in my cs50 speller code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

So I know it is shameless to ask someone on the internet to debug my code, but I have drained my pea-sized brain to the limit and I still can't solve this (my rubber duck has fled my desk in order to get some peace). All joking aside, I am having trouble with the pset5: **speller**, from cs50. Thing is, that after finishing all the tedious coding process and finally being able to compile my code *free of errors* I am, of course, getting the annoying **segfault**.

Now for the "interesting and fun" part: when executing the check50 function that is provided by the cs50 teaching staff I get all the green ticks, as if my code is working... which is very confusing.

Here is my code:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 150001; //Bigger than word count for enough buckets (Not concerned about memory space)

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Variable with the amount of words in the dictionary
int count = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // hash word for value in table
    int hash_value = hash(word);

    // access list at hash value and compare words (strcompare)
    node *p = table[hash_value];

    // loop to end of linked list
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, p->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
/*CREDIT: JR(joseph28robinson) from website medium.com for helping with HASH TABLE theory*/
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    long x = 0;

    // Improve this hash function
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        // I am unsure if the subtraction of 'A' is needed
        x += toupper(word[i]);
    }

    return x % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open file
    FILE *dict_file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dictionary == NULL)
    {
        // Could not open dictionary
        return false;
    }

    // Buffer for reading file
    char new_word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Scan file for every word and create a new node for each one
    // (NOT SURE WHY ==1 instead of != EOF /*CREDIT: Creig Estey comment from stackoverflow.com*/)
    while (fscanf(dict_file, "%s", new_word) == 1)
    {
        // Get word's hash value
        int hash_value = hash(new_word);

        // Malloc space for node
        node *p = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (p == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Fill in new node's variables
        strcpy(p->word, new_word);

        // TODO: Check for available space in hash's table hash_value node or create linked list
        if (table[hash_value] == NULL)
        {
            // First item in bucket so pointer to NULL
            p->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            // Not first item in bucket so pointer to first item in list (LINKED LIST THEORY)
            p->next = table[hash_value];
        }
        // Point bucket to new node
        table[hash_value] = p;

        // Update size of dict
        count++;
    }

    // Close file
    fclose(dict_file);

    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // No need to insert if function to check if dict loaded since count is already set to 0 (it will return 0 if not loaded)
    return count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // Iterate through all buckets of hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // Access hash's table bucket
        node *p = table[i];

        // Loop through all items (linked list) in bucket
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            // Use trav pointer not to orphan list
            node *trav = p;
            // Point to next element in list
            p = p->next;
            // Free trav
            free(trav);
        }

        // End of loop condition to return true
        if (p == NULL && i == N - 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tried using the debugger and I have checked every possible (to my knowledge) NULL return when working with memory. I am assuming that therein lies the problem, although at this point I am not so sure.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: You should run your program in a debugger. It should immediately show you *where*  the segfault happens. Then you can inspect the involved variables and start searching *why* it happens.

Comment: post a small dict file you used for test so we can just reproduce your scenario

Comment: `hash` function returns `unsigned int`, but you assign it to `int` (in `check` function) what may cause problems, since you're using it as and index of an array

Comment: where are `strings.h` and `dictionary.h`?

Comment: Unrelated: That check `if (table[hash_value] == NULL)` in `load` function is useless. You can just do `p->next = table[hash_value];` in any case.

Comment: That check `if (p == NULL && i == N - 1)` in `unload` function is also not required. That condition is identical with just leaving the outer loop. You can just move that `return` after the loop.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions! I actually kept running it through the debugger, applied the few suggested changes in the code, and it ended up working. Still unsure of why I ran into seg-fault problem... but, tbh, I am glad it's over.

Comment: " Still unsure of why I ran into seg-fault problem... but, tbh, I am glad it's over." -- It's (likely) _not_ over. This is "programming by coincidence", and you should _not_ do that if you want to succeed in CS field. https://daedtech.com/high-stakes-programming-coincidence

Answer (score 0):

There ois a potential problem in the code when reading the dictionary file:

```
 while (fscanf(dict_file, "%s", new_word) == 1)
```

If there is a word in the dictionary that is longer than `LENGTH` characters, `fscanf()` will cause a buffer overflow trying to store it into `new_word`.

You should pass the maximum number of characters to `fscanf()` or use a custom function to read a word:

```
#include <ctype.h>

char *read_word(char *buf, size_t size, FILE *fp) {
    size_t i;
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            if (i == 0)
                continue;
            else
                break;
        } else {
            if (i + 1 < size)
                buf[i++] = (char)c;
        }
    }
    if (i == 0)
        return NULL;
    buf[i] = '\0';
    return buf;
}
```

Then you would replace the `while` loop with:

```
while (get_word(new_word, sizeof new_word, dict_file))
```

The hash function can be improved: `char` values must be cast as `(unsigned char)` when passed to `toupper()` because this function is only defined for positive values and `EOF` and `char` may be signed on the target platform.  Furthermore, `hash` should be unsigned to avoid overflow issues and negative result from the modulo operation:

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned long x = 0;

    // Improve this hash function
    for (size_t i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        // subtraction of 'A' is not needed
        x += toupper((unsigned char)word[i]);
    }
    return x % N;
}
```